# How to get HDD parameters from SCSI controller

Tags: hardware-raid, scsi, centos6.2

The SCSI controller we are using is IBM RAID M1015 and a SATA 3 HDD is attached to it. Now the question, is there any way to get the HDD specific parameters like HDD Model number/Manufacturer, Storage Size, rpm, transfer speed (3/6 Gbps?) etc...

Tried, `hdparm -I /dev/sda` but failed with  `HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange`

`Disk utility` shows the RAID controller M1015 as HDD Model Name, as is the case with `gparted`

Any idea!

Comment: For future reference: The SCSI version of hdparm is named "sdparm" - see http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdparm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IBM RAID M1015 is a RAID controller virtualizing your storage, you cannot access the single drive's properties via standard SATA/SAS commands (which is what `hdparm` and `smartctl` try do) unless you are running [the IT version of the firmware](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19203-01/820-4933-15/bios_util_intro.html#0_98467). However, as it is a LSI 9211-8i with customized firmware, you should be able to run the [MegaCLI command line utility](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5082327) to list the state (and properties) of the connected physical drives:

```
megacli -pdlist  -aALL | less
```

The output information will include the drive's serial number in the "Inquiry Data" field of the output:

```
[...]
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c5003abb8c15
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST3600057SS     00012SL42BN0
[...]
```

Comment: cool, worked like a charm. `/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -pdlist  -aALL`